# Search only within an Org Sparse Tree

Tags: org-mode, isearch

I use `org-mode` to write a huge research diary with thousands of entries. I'm trying to organize them by tags. I make only the relevant entries appear via org-sparse-tree and that works perfectly. Now, I would like to use the Emacs search only among them. Is this possible?

Alternatively, is it possible to export a org-sparse-tree to another buffer and search there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dunno anything about Org or `org-sparse-tree`. But if it makes only some text visible by making the rest of the text invisible, then Isearch should automatically do the right thing: search only the visible text.

However, you might need to set (or bind, in, e.g., a command you write), option `search-invisible` to `nil`.  The default value is `open`, which means that certain invisible text can be matched (opened) by Isearch.  `C-h v search-invisible` tells you:

> **`search-invisible`** is a variable defined in `isearch.el`.
>
> Its value is open
>
> Documentation:
>
> If `t` incremental search/query-replace can match hidden text.
>
> A `nil` value means don't match invisible text.
>
> When the value is `open`, if the text matched is made invisible by
>   an overlay having an `invisible` property and that overlay has a property
>   `isearch-open-invisible`, then incremental search will show the contents.
>   (This applies when using `outline.el` and `hideshow.el`.)
>
> To temporarily change the value for an active incremental search,
>   use `M-s i`.
>
> See also the related option `isearch-hide-immediately`.
>
> See also `reveal-mode` if you want overlays to automatically be opened
>   whenever point is in one of them.
>
> You can customize this variable.

As that doc also says, you can use `M-s i` to toggle the value temporarily.

But of course, this variable has an effect only on overlays with property `invisible` and property `isearch-open-invisible`.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about that! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

[Drew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew) answers the first section.

> Alternatively, is it possible to export a org-sparse-tree to another
>   buffer and search there?

It's in the docs.  `(info "(org) Sparse trees")`

> Or you can use `C-c C-e C-v` to export only the visible part of the
>   document and print the resulting file.

You could choose the option `O O` for exporting into an org mode buffer.